# Sublime Text 3: Customize certain syntax highlighting

Tags: sublime-text-3

(I am aware that this and similar questions have been asked already. But I am still confused.)

Example case: I have installed the `LaTeXing` package for `LaTeX` and I am using the `ayu-light` Color Scheme. (I am not sure whether these specifics are relevant or not.)

Say I want to change the syntax coloring of `LaTeX` comments. In the given set up, it is gray in italics. I do not want it to be in italics. (And perhaps change the color, too.)

Question:

1) Is it the `LaTeXing` package or the `ayu-light` Color Scheme controlling that? (Or both?)

2) What is the way to, for this example, make the italic comments ((1) in the context of LaTex; (2) in general) make non-italic.

3) Whatever the procedure for this specific example is, is it the same for all packages and color schemes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your first question could have been answered by switching your theme. A syntax definition only defines the rules, which part of a syntax gets assigned to a scope. It's the theme that's entirely responsible for the styling.

To change the styling, follow these steps:

1. Clone the original theme and rename it, otherwise it will be overwritten by updates
2. Make your changes

More specifically, remove (or comment) [lines 75 and 76](https://github.com/dempfi/ayu/blob/57a2aa32b7b779b697f74bf93a6da9ae8a05b8c8/ayu-light.tmTheme#L75-L76) from the theme:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comment</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>comment, punctuation.definition.comment</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <!--
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>italic</string>
        -->
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#ABB0B6</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Side question: Is there a mechanism to select something and where the relative syntax/coloring or whatever defined in the theme file. (For example, say I select a comment, right-click (and whatever) then I learn that it is defined in line 76 in the theme. (It doesn't have to be exactly as described, obviously.))

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. The closest thing I know is *Tools > Developer > Show Scope Name* (or `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`P`), it prints the scope at cursor position. You can then search for that in the theme.